# Can't close tkinter root window after modalPane closed

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, window, python-2.x

I've cloned a class called `ListBoxChoice` found on the web found (adding some needed features) below:

```
from Tkinter import *

class ListBoxChoice(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None, title=None, message=None,\
                 list=[]):
    self.master = master
    self.value = None
    self.list = list[:]

    self.modalPane = Toplevel(self.master)

    self.modalPane.transient(self.master)
    self.modalPane.grab_set()

    self.modalPane.bind("<Return>", self._choose)
    self.modalPane.bind("<Escape>", self._cancel)

    if title:
        self.modalPane.title(title)

    if message:
        Label(self.modalPane, text=message).pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    listFrame = Frame(self.modalPane)
    listFrame.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

    scrollBar = Scrollbar(listFrame)
    scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    # get the largest value of the 'list' to set the width
    widthOfList = 0
    for k in list:
        if len(str(k)) > widthOfList:
            widthOfList = len(str(k))

    # now pad some space to back of the widthOfList
    widthOfList = widthOfList + 2

    self.listBox = Listbox(listFrame, selectmode=SINGLE,\
                   width=widthOfList)

    self.listBox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    scrollBar.config(command=self.listBox.yview)

    self.listBox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
    self.list.sort()

    for item in self.list:
        self.listBox.insert(END, item)

    buttonFrame = Frame(self.modalPane)
    buttonFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    chooseButton = Button(buttonFrame, text="Choose",\
                   command=self._choose)
    chooseButton.pack()

    cancelButton = Button(buttonFrame, text="Cancel",\
                   command=self._cancel)
    cancelButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def _choose(self, event=None):
        try:
            firstIndex = self.listBox.curselection()[0]
            self.value = self.list[int(firstIndex)]
        except IndexError:
            self.value = None
        self.modalPane.destroy()

    def _cancel(self, event=None):
        self.modalPane.destroy()

    def returnValue(self):
        self.master.wait_window(self.modalPane)
        return self.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    root = Tk()

    returnValue = True
    list = [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(50)]
    while returnValue:
        returnValue = ListBoxChoice(root, "Number Picking",\
                     "Pick one of these crazy random numbers",\
                     list).returnValue()
        print returnValue
```

Now this example says to do something like this:
`results = ListBoxChoice(root, list=listOfItems).returnValue()`.

What I'm trying to do is provide a list of values from which the user selects a single value.  The window should close before I use the results from the selected value. Here is that code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
form ListBoxChoice import ListBoxChoice
...
eventList = ["20190120","20190127","20190203"]
root = Tk()
root.withdraw() # This causes the ListBoxChoice object not to appear
selectValue = ListBoxChoice(root, title="Event",\
              message="Pick Event", list=eventList).returnValue()
root.wait_window() # Modal Pane/window closes but not the root
print("selectValue:", selectValue)
```

A `root` window is placed behind the `modalPane` (`Toplevel`).  I have to close that window before the calling process continues.  So there is a block in place.

I've tried to put a `sleep(1.01)` command above but had no impact.
How do I get the `ListBoxChoice` to close once the selection has been made
before my `print` statement of the `selectValue`?  For it is at that point I want to use the results to plot data.

If I don't use `root.wait_winow()`, it is only when the plot is closed (end of the process) that the `ListBoxChoice` box close as well.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly updated

Here's a version of the `ListBoxChoice` class which I think works the way you desire. I've updated my previous answer slightly so the class is now defined in a separate module named `listboxchoice.py`. This didn't change anything I could see when I tested—it other words it still seems to work—but I wanted to more closely simulate the way you said you're using it the comments.

It still uses `wait_window()` because doing so is *required* to give tkinter's mandatory event-processing-loop the opportunity to run (since `mainloop()` isn't called anywhere). There's some good background material in the article [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) about programming tkiner dialogs you might find useful. The added `root.withdraw()` call eliminates the issue of not being able to close it because it's not there. This is fine since there's no need to have the empty window being displayed anyway.

#### `test_lbc.py`

```
import random
try:
    import Tkinter as tk  # Python 2
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import tkinter as tk  # Python 3
from listboxchoice import ListBoxChoice


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()  # Hide root window.

values = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(50)]
choice = None

while choice is None:
    choice = ListBoxChoice(root, "Number Picking",
                           "Pick one of these crazy random numbers",
                           values).returnValue()
print('choice: {}'.format(choice))
```

#### `listboxchoice.py`

```
""" ListBoxChoice widget to display a list of values and allow user to
    choose one of them.
"""
try:
    import Tkinter as tk  # Python 2
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import tkinter as tk  # Python 3


class ListBoxChoice(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None, title=None, message=None, values=None):
        self.master = master
        self.value = None
        if values is None:  # Avoid use of mutable default argument value.
            raise RuntimeError('No values argument provided.')
        self.values = values[:]  # Create copy.

        self.modalPane = tk.Toplevel(self.master, takefocus=True)
        self.modalPane.bind("<Return>", self._choose)
        self.modalPane.bind("<Escape>", self._cancel)

        if title:
            self.modalPane.title(title)

        if message:
            tk.Label(self.modalPane, text=message).pack(padx=5, pady=5)

        listFrame = tk.Frame(self.modalPane)
        listFrame.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

        scrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(listFrame)
        scrollBar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Get length the largest value in 'values'.
        widthOfList = max(len(str(value)) for value in values)
        widthOfList += 2  # Add some padding.

        self.listBox = tk.Listbox(listFrame, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, width=widthOfList)

        self.listBox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        scrollBar.config(command=self.listBox.yview)

        self.listBox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
        self.values.sort()

        for item in self.values:
            self.listBox.insert(tk.END, item)

        buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self.modalPane)
        buttonFrame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        chooseButton = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Choose", command=self._choose)
        chooseButton.pack()

        cancelButton = tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Cancel", command=self._cancel)
        cancelButton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def _choose(self, event=None):
        try:
            firstIndex = self.listBox.curselection()[0]
            self.value = self.values[int(firstIndex)]
        except IndexError:
            self.value = None
        self.modalPane.destroy()

    def _cancel(self, event=None):
        self.modalPane.destroy()

    def returnValue(self):
        self.master.wait_window(self.modalPane)
        return self.value
```

Comment: martineau thanks for your response.  In looking at the import of "T"kinter versus "t"kinter, "Tkinter" is python 2, "tkinter is python 3.  Not using python 2.  That might be a problem if python 3 doesn't function the same as python 2.  Otherwise I replicated your code but the same problem presists with one exception. Placing the root.withdraw() statement at the bottom prevents the window with the data from presented.  Further ideas?

Comment: Doubt it's a Python 2 vs 3 issue because other than how things are `import`ed there are virtually no differences in using the module or what it does. Note however that I also made modifications to the `ListBoxChoice` class—in other words more was done than simply adding a `root.withdraw()`.

Comment: martineau - yes, I saw and implemented the changes you refer to within the class.  There are still 2 windows presented initially.  The window providing the listbox (data) is closed after the value is selected. However, the root window (I believe) is still there (nothing on it).  Once that closes (close the window), the program resumes and does what its supposed to do.

Comment: Hmm, well, it sounds like it's either an OS difference (I'm using Windows) or it's because I'm running the code standalone—not as part of some other processing as you appear to doing.

Comment: Yeah I think so.  I'm using Linux (red hat 7.5) and I'm interfacing to it importing the class then calling it.  When I run it in stand-alone it does as you indicated.  Unfortunately, I need to interface with it from may places I was hoping this could be a basic tool that others could use. Not sure now.  If you have other ideas I would be most interested.

Comment: Have modified my answer a bit so it could be used in a manner similar to that and it still works for me—but take a look and see if there's some difference I missing. Note there's was a typo in how the the Tkinter `import`ing was being done, which I didn't notice before, but I doubt that was the cause of the different behavior you're describing.

Comment: Martineau, I took the changes and reviewed my code and tweaked it some but yes now its working as planned.  1 window, select an item from the list and the box closes after the choice is made and code is returned to the calling program.  It seems the root window {root = tk.Tk()} followed by {root.withdraw()} before calling theListBoxChoice and the {root.wait_window()} is not necessary.

Comment: That's good to hear. If used from another tkinter app with its own window, you shouldn't call `Tk()` again (more than once is a no-no), nor would you generally need (or want) to do a `root.withdraw()`.